# Why xampp setup is not running correctly in windows 8.1

Tags: xampp

I have the problem with setup.Setup wont install correctly.It says "apache server has stopped working" but setup installing continues and  says "CLI has stopped working".But still setup continues installing and says creating uninstaller.Finally setup got finish and ask to start control pannel.
Mysql works properly but apache server wont start working.

Comment: Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall XAMPP Server
2. Restart your PC
3. Stop UAC (User Account Control Setting)
4. Install latest version of XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html (64bit) or use portable version :
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.12/

if you have a problem with starting the Apache service check the port 80. (change the default port to 8080 in the config file)